# Can I use Azure MFA without use its SSO login?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, multi-factor-authentication

I want to support MFA(Multiple factor authentication) in my web app and iOS app. And my customer suggests us to use Azure MFA.

But I only find document about how to enable Azure MFA if app is integrate with Azure AD and SSO page.

My Question is: Can I use Azure's MFA service with my custom login page? but not Azure's login page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If a user has MFA, they must login through the Azure AD login page.